# Changing price shown in opencart 3.x

Tags: php, opencart-3, opencart-module

I've been trying to upgrade my website from opencart 2.2 to version 3.0.3.1
To do this I have created a sandbox copy of my website where all the modules and the theme are re-installed in version 3.0.3.1.

All the database information has been transferred and everything seems to be working like intended.

My only issue is with the option-combination extension available for purchase in opencart, the prices don't seem to work properly with the journal 3 theme modules.

This means that all the modules included with the journal 3 theme display a 0 price when the product uses option-combination.

I have found all the controller files for the modules inside:

mysite/catalog/controller/journal3

and in every file I have found the code that controls the displayed price (see below)

in said code I tried changing ($result['price'], into ($result['starting_from'],

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }
```

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

doing this causes the opposite problem, all the products that have option-combination display the correct price and all the ones that don't display 0.

the current site has it setup like this:

it shows the customer_group_price (discount tab)
and if the discount tab is empty it shows the otp_customer_price (option-combination price)

I am terrible with code and php is probably my worst enemy, so if someone has anyway to rewrite that code to work properly I would really appreciate it.

Comment: "My only issue is with the option-combination extension available for purchase in opencart, the prices don't seem to work properly with the journal 3 theme modules."
Contact the developer of the extension.

Comment: I did, he said to wait 4 weeks for the compleatly remodelled version of the module, problem is it won't work with old settings and needs to be adapted to my site for a price. I would rather avoid that, as I said before I just need it to show the right price and I'm ready to go.

Comment: We work with OpenCart all day every day and we still sometimes have problems working with Journal as it's very complex. So IMO you might be better off saving the time and paying the money.

Comment: yeah i really won't save any time since I still need to wait 4 weeks for the module to be ready.